# Trying to build a Python class in a C extension that can be instantiated from a Python module

Tags: python

I'm trying to build an exception class that I can use both in a C extension and the Python modules that import the extension.  I'm using the PyErr_NewException to create the class as a superclass of the Exception class, but I can't figure out how to create an `__init__` constructor for the class.  I assume that is the best way to populate the class with the attributes I need.

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: PyObject*   failure;PyObject*   module = Py_InitModule3("andro", methods, moduleDocstring);
    int         fd;
    unsigned    device;
    Api         api;

    if (module != NULL)
    {   // The module init was successful
        failure = PyErr_NewException( "andro.Failure", NULL, Py_BuildValue("{}"));

        PyModule_AddObject(module, "Failure", failure);

Answer (score 0):

You should pass a `dict` as the third argument to `PyErr_NewException`.  The dict should have an `__init__` key bound to your initializer function.

Comment: I have explored that but I can't tell what kind of object to associate with the "__init__" key.  Is it a code object?

Comment: A function, I guess.  I found some semi-interesting examples when I searched online.